# Align large image inside the ImageView without scaling

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I am trying to display a large image (wider than screen) inside the ImageView and I use matrix scale type.

```
<ImageView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/pizza_intro_test"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:scaleType="matrix" 
        />
```

However, I am not able to align the image inside the ImageView. I would like to display "right" part of the image but ImageView displays "left" part instead.

This is the current state:

[image: Current state]

This is the state I am trying to achieve:

[image: Desired state]

Answer (score 0):

Checkout Matrix.setRectToRect method and try to implement it.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#setRectToRect%28android.graphics.RectF,%20android.graphics.RectF,%20android.graphics.Matrix.ScaleToFit%29

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the gravity of your imageview to right.

```
<ImageView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/pizza_intro_test"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:scaleType="matrix" 
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar by setting source and destination Rect. The trick is to use negative value on the destination Rect. That way you can "start drawing" the left side of the image outside the visible canvas, and the right side will be drawn on the canvas itself.

The destination rect should be something like this:

```
float scale = canvas.getHeight() / (float)bm.getHeight(); 
Rect dest = new Rect(canvas.getWidth()-bm.getWidth()*scale,canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight())
```

you can define it on the onDraw() and use it with

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bm, null, mDstRect, mPaint);
```

You don't need to set any scaleType on the XML or code.

Comment: Can you please clarify your answer? Do you extend ImageView? I do understand your code but I'am not sure where to use it.

Comment: Yes, you extends ImageView, save the bitmap locally, override the onDraw() method and use the code I gave to draw the bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is too late, but even I ran into the same problem today and fixed it by using the following snippet.

All the alignment/scaling options are in the scaleType attribute.

Now, if you want to align the image with the beginning of the ImageView, use **`android:scaleType="fitStart"`**.

Similarly, **`android:scaleType="fitEnd"`** to align it with the bottom of the ImageView.

Comment: The picture is not cropped with android:scaleType="fitStart" anymore.

Comment: Yes, it won't be. You can't define multiple scaleTypes. What I did was  crop it myself programmatically and set it.